# how to setup a $http post on a mobile app

Tags: angularjs, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to login and make a post to my project on my web host. I have removed the cors issue by adding the cors attribute to my web api 2 controller and my WebApiConfig.cs file. When I make a post with my login information included my console.log message shows the html of my login.cshtml file that is on my web host. And the "Job" information I am trying to post is not being posted as well.

Angular Controller

```
  $scope.submitJob = function () {
    var data = {
        username: $scope.currentItem.username,
        password: $scope.currentItem.password,

        JobId: $scope.JobId,
        JobNumber: $scope.currentItem.JobNumber,
        JobName: $scope.currentItem.JobName,

    }
    var json = JSON.stringify(data);
    // json is the json data you need to post

    $http.post('http://www.example.com/api/apiJob', json, { headers: { 'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } })
            .success(function (data, status) {
                console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function (data, status) {
                // error code
            });
};
```

Web Api 2 Controller

```
 [Authorize]
[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]
public class apiJobController : ApiController
{

    // GET api/<controller>
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public IEnumerable<JobResult> Get()
    {
        using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            return context.Jobs

           .ToResults();
        }

    }
    // GET api/<controller>/5
    public Job GetJob(int? id)
    {
        using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            Job model = new Job();
            model = context.Jobs
                .FirstOrDefault(j => j.JobId == id);
            return model;
        }
    }

    // POST api/<controller>
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PostnewJob([FromBody]JobViewModel newJob)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            return BadRequest(ModelState);
        }

        using (var context = new ApplicationDbContext())
        {
            var job = new Job();

            Mapper.CreateMap<JobViewModel, Job>();
            Mapper.Map(newJob, job);
            context.Jobs.Add(job);

            await context.SaveChangesAsync();

            return CreatedAtRoute("JobApi", new { job.JobId }, job);
        }
    }
```

Screenshot
[image: screenshot]

Comment: You usually don't have to do JSON.stringify() on data that you POST with $http. Now maybe that's required for your web server. Have you tried it by not stringifying the data?

Comment: just tried it, its still doing the same thing. why is it returning the html in the console?

Comment: I dont know what to google?

Comment: It's most likely something to do w/your web server. I normally use Rails, and when I see this sort of thing happening it's because the request I made did not match the "routing rules" defined for my server. And typically, for single page apps (like we create w/Angular), you have a "catchall" routing rule that serves up the main web page when the requested URL is not known. But there could be many other reasons why your server is doing that.

Comment: I have the project setup, once the user logs in through the default razor view, the index in the home controller reroutes to the app/index.html view. Is it something like that which causes problems?